# What is the difference between "OneVsRestClassifier" (Scikit-learn) and "Binary Relevance" (Scikit-multilearn)?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification, scikit-multilearn

In scikit-learn, there is a strategy called `sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier`, which can be used for both multiclass and multilabel problems. According to its [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html):

> "In the multilabel learning literature, OvR is also known as the binary relevance method".

My question is,

Is there is any difference between this scikit-learn strategy and `skmultilearn.problem_transform.BinaryRelevance`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no difference. They work in the exact same way. They both predict probabilities for an instance belonging to a class, yes or no.